# Sum computed columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spread sheet that has scores and then players and need to take the scores of match and place the score of the team the player was on then sum all 10 game together.  I am using = IF ( B7 =1, Left(C6, 2), Right(C6, 2)) in each cell of each game for each player to put their score in the correct box based on who won but the sum at the end no longer functions.  How do I get that sum column to add each cell that I need together when using an if then to pull the correct number?

Thanks.

Comment: Its a bit hard to follow your question. Perhaps you can put a screenshot of how your data model looks like?

Comment: =arrayformula( value( if( X7: X18= 1, left(Y6:Y6, 2), right(Y6:Y6, 2) ) ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=arrayformula( value( if( X7: X18= 1, left(Y6:Y6, 2), right(Y6:Y6, 2) ) ))

The problem was I did not use value so when it tried to compute the line it didn't have anything to compute!